# Why does zip eagerly evaluate the elements of its arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, iterable-unpacking

Using the following definitions:

```
def a(x):
    return x + 1

def b(x):
    return x + 2
```

`[map(a, range(3)), map(b, range(3)]` results in `[<iterator>, <iterator>]`. I am trying to replicate this functionality without having to construct the `range` iterator twice.

I've made this function:

```
def map_many(mappers, values):
    def get_many(value):
        for mapper in mappers:
            yield mapper(value)

    mapped_values = map(get_many, values)
    return zip(*mapped_values)
```

Doing:

```
for my_iterator in map_many((a, b), range(3)):
    print(my_iterator)
```

results in:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 4)
```

Why is `my_iterator` eagerly evaluated? I would have expected it to still be an iterator that would be lazily evaluated (that, when printed, would show up as something along the lines of `<iterator>`). The `*` before `mapped_values`, to my understanding, unpacks `mapped_values` itself (which is an iterators of iterators), rather than unpacking all the iterators that would be returned by continually calling `next(mapped_values)`.

Is it possible to have each `my_iterator` remain as an iterator and lazily evaluated, rather than being converted to a `tuple`?

Comment: In Python 2 you may be looking for [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead of `zip`.  In Python 3 it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the motivation behind your function. You can iterate as many times as you want on a `range` object, and it's very efficient. Doing almost any alternative is going to be worse. Is your actual use case trying to work with iterators that you can't consume more than once, in place of the `range`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip), it's equivalent to:

```
def zip(*iterables):
    # zip('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax By
    sentinel = object()
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    while iterators:
        result = []
        for it in iterators:
            elem = next(it, sentinel)
            if elem is sentinel:
                return
            result.append(elem)
        yield tuple(result)
```

As you can see, it does evaluate each of the iterators it's given, and calls `next` on each of them until at least one of them is exhausted. From this perspective, what you're seeing is the expected behavior.